# Proof that the image of an Itō integral is convex if the driving Wiener process is in a metric ball

Tags: stochastic-processes, convex-analysis, stochastic-integrals

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $A := \int_0^1 f(t)\,d W_t$ be the Itō integral of an $L_2([0,1])$ deterministic function $f$ with respect to the Wiener process $W$. Additionally, define the set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\textstyle
B:= \{A(\omega) \,|\, \omega\in C \},
$$
where
$$
\textstyle
C:= \{\omega\in\Omega \,|\, \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|W_t(\omega)|< 1\}.
$$
How can I prove that the set $B$ is convex and symmetric?

### Context

This statement (that $B$ is convex) is used by [Shepp and Zeitouni (1992, p. 654)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176989796). They mention it as something obvious in less than a line and proceed to use it to obtain their result. I'm trying to generalize their result slightly and am not sure where this statement comes from, and why it holds. While I could simply say that Shepp and Zeitouni say it is true, I'm stubborn and would like a formal proof.

Obs.: the article by Shepp and Zeitouni is open access and can be freely downloaded.

### Research

This seems to follow trivially if the Itō integral of deterministic $L_2$ functions is linear with respect to the integrator $W$. I know that if $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of piecewise constant (simple) functions such that $f_i\to f$ in $L_2([0,1])$ then $A_i:=\int_0^1 f_i(t)\,dW_t$ are linear with respect to the integrator $W$. Although $A_i\to A$ in $L_2(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P)$, I'm not sure if this implies anything in terms of the linearity of $A$ with respect to $W$.

Also, since $A$ is formally defined as the $L_2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$-limit of $A_i$, it is defined as an element of $L_2$, which is a space of equivalence classes of functions, identified by equality $P$-almost everywhere. That is, if some $A'\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is such that $A'=A$ almost surely, then it is the same element of $L_2(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$. This seems to leave some ambiguity in the definition of $B$, allowing it to be non-convex and non-symmetric. Consequently, it seems more appropriate to say that there exists some $B'$ which is convex and symmetric but differs from $B$ by a measure zero set.

Comment: But the Itō integral of deterministic L2 functions **IS** linear with respect to the function, no?

Comment: It is definitely linear with respect to the integrand, but I'm not sure with respect to the integrator. If we construct the integral as limit of the integral of a sequence of simple functions, each element of the sequence is linear with respect to the integrator, but thus that guarantee that the $L_2(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P)$-limit is linear?

Comment: Also, it should only be some kind of $P$-almost everywhere linearity (if that even makes sense) because $A$, as an $L_2$-limit is only unique up to equality almost everywhere, so there is some "ambiguity" in the definition of its image.

Comment: I edited the question to explain better the context and the research I've done.

Comment: OK, so if we consider that $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ is the the classical Wiener space, then finite variance linear functionals of the Wiener process $\omega$ form a subspace of $L_2(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ which is also a Hilbert space and thus complete. So $A$ IS linear with respect to the Wiener process $\omega$ since it belongs to that subspace. The functions which are almost surely linear with respect to $\omega$ (which makes more sense when talking about $L_2$) are also a linear subspace, so the same applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is not a full answer but I think that with some little work you should get to the answer using those ideas.

First remark, if $f=1$ then $A=W_1$ so if $x\in B$ then $-x\in B$  as the path $-\omega \in C$. Convexity follows by the same line of reasoning.

Now try to extend this to simple functions of the form $f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i 1[t\in O_i ]  $ where $O_i$ form a borelian partition of $[0,1]$, and $\lambda_i$ are real. Then extend the result by a density argument to $f\in L^2([0,1])$.

Best regards

Comment: OK, I understand that for any sequence of simple functions $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $f_i\to f$ in $L_2([0,1])$, the image of $A_i:=\int_0^1 f_i(t)dW_t$ restricted to $C$ is convex and symmetric. Additionally, $A_i\to A$ in $L_2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Does that imply that the image of the limit is convex and symmetric?

Comment: @ Dimas : I think that in a Hilbert space this should remain true. Regards

Comment: @ TheBridge Do you have any references?

Comment: @ Dimas : nope you should try to prove it.Best regards.